# Rotation and timer at the same time

Tags: c#, unity, 2d

I have a project where I flip a card after 5 seconds, then I want to start a countdown timer of x seconds. After x seconds the card flips again.

I found a good example for the timer [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/273094/unity3d-timer-request.html), but that works inside a Update() method. My problem comes from the fact that the rotation of the card is made also inside the Update() method.

If I put the timer inside the Update() method, as soon as the Update() method is called the timer starts, and I don't want it to start it as soon as I call the Update() method, but when I want to start ip, wich is 60 seconds after I flip the card.

If I put the timer inside a method other than Update() then the timer start but never decrease.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class Juego1Carta2 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float velocidadDeRotacion = 100.0f;
     public Sprite cartaBase;
     public Sprite cartaDelantera;
     private bool carta2Activada = false;
     private bool cartaDeLado = false;
     float tiempoDeJuego = 2;
     IEnumerator Esperar()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
         transform.position = new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2 +GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y, 0);
         carta2Activada = true;
         Regresa();
     }
void Regresa()
{
    Update();
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine (Esperar());
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (carta2Activada)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * velocidadDeRotacion);
        if (transform.eulerAngles.y >= 90)
        {
            SpriteRenderer Carta = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            if (Carta.sprite == cartaBase)
            {
                Carta.sprite = cartaDelantera;
                cartaDeLado = true;
                carta2Activada = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Carta.sprite = cartaBase;
                cartaDeLado = true;
                carta2Activada = false;
            }
            tiempoDeJuego = 60;
        }
    }
    tiempoDeJuego -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (tiempoDeJuego <= 0)
    {
        print("Fin del tiempo");
    }
    if (cartaDeLado)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * velocidadDeRotacion);
        if (transform.eulerAngles.y >= 180)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            cartaDeLado = false;
            carta2Activada = false;
            return;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to rotate the card and make a countdown timer at the same time?

I'm sorry, maybe this is a very obvious question but after 3 consecutive days working on this, I'm more than burnout...

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Update` incorrectly. `Update` is called automatically every frame by Unity, on every component attached to every object (you can see this with the default comment that still exists in your code `// Update is called once per frame`). You don't need to call `Update` manually.

I see you're aware of having conditionals in the Update loop. What's wrong with having a `if(timerStarted)` conditional statement and putting all the timer code inside that? Then when you want to start your timer, just set `timerStarted` to true.

You can use use the coroutine like you are now, or simply have a different timer that sets `timerStarted` to true. Either one, will be activated in the `Start()` method, and 5 seconds later, `timerStarted` will be set to true, and will start being activated inside the `Update` loop.